# Convert "\\n" to a newline character

Tags: c++

I'm parsing a stream one character at a time, as in the highly simplified example below. My problem is that I need to translate the `\\n` to an actual newline character (and similarly for any other escaped characters).

Is there a better way than the manual way I've done it here? Because that becomes rather cumbersome if I have to convert every possible escape character that way.

```
char c ;
std::stringstream s("foo \\n bar") ;

while (s.good()) {
    c = s.get() ;
    if (!s.good()) break ;
    if (c == '\\' && s.get() == 'n') c = '\n' ;
    std::cout << c ;
}
```

Comment: Keep a list of all possibilities, then check if the next is in there when you hit a backslash.

Comment: .Addition to chris's sugggetion, you can make use of regex searching.

Comment: @diegoperini - "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

Comment: @Dai: Apologies, that's me assuming that some people already have necessary knowledge to work with regex. I should definetly add some suggestion to lead to a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re basically writing a simple lexer; the usual approach to doing this by hand is to use a state machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char c;
  istringstream s("foo \\n bar");
  enum { CHARACTER, ESCAPE } state = CHARACTER;

  while (s.get(c)) {    
    switch (state) {
    case CHARACTER:
      if (c == '\\') {
        state = ESCAPE;
      } else {
        cout << c;
      }
      break;

    case ESCAPE:
      switch (c) {
      case 'n': cout << '\n'; break;
      case 't': cout << '\t'; break;
      default:
        throw runtime_error("unknown escape");
      }
      state = CHARACTER;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course for this simple example, the escape table could be a `map<char, char>`, but if you want to support more exotic escapes such as `\xNN` where `NN` are hex digits, then it can pay to generalise.

The advantage to the state machine approach is that there is *one* location where characters are read. Individual states are only responsible for adding that character to the output how they see fit, and making transitions to other states by assigning the `state` variable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing something similar with the states in the full code, but your example makes it clearer. Based on the answers so far, I guess there's not much reason to think there's some brilliant way to combine the two chars into one, so to speak, except manually.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
int c;     // Not char.
while((c = s.get() != EOF)
{
    if (c == '\\')
    {
        switch(int escaped = s.get())
        {
           case 't':
              c = '\t';
              break;
           case 'n':
              c = '\n';
              break;
           case 'a':
              c = '\a';
           ...
           default:
              std::cout << c << escaped;    // Retain "invalid variants". 
              c = 0; 
              break;
        }
    }
    if (c)
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Note that if you want a COMPLETE solution you will also need to handle `\033`, `\x1b` and `\u0417` (random non-printable characters in octal or hex, and unicode characters respectively)

Comment: Better add a `default` case that shows *both* the original backslash and the unparsed character.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit cumbersome, and I never knew there were so many escapes, but that's life I guess

Answer (score 1):

Your code is largely correct, though I don't feel it's particularly cumbersome at all.

However your code has a bug: if you have this as input: `'\\', 'g'` then the `g' character will be lost because you don't preserve the data retrieved by your second`s.get()` call.

This is how I'd do it:

```
bool escaped = false;
while (s.good()) {
    c = s.get() ;
    if (!s.good()) break ;
    if( escaped ) {
        if( c == 'n' ) {
            std::cout << '\n' ;
        } else {
            std::cout << '\\' << c;
        }
        escaped = false;
    } else {
        if( c == '\\' ) {
            escaped = true;
        } else {
            std::cout << c ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it for use in C++ as-is, but here's some code I wrote around 20 years ago in C that might provide a little inspiration.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *translate(char *string)
{
      char *here=string;
      size_t len=strlen(string);
      int num;
      int numlen;

      while (NULL!=(here=strchr(here,'\\')))
      {
            numlen=1;
            switch (here[1])
            {
            case '\\':
                  break;

            case 'r':
                  *here = '\r';
                  break;

            case 'n':
                  *here = '\n';
                  break;

            case 't':
                  *here = '\t';
                  break;

            case 'v':
                  *here = '\v';
                  break;

            case 'a':
                  *here = '\a';
                  break;

            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
                  numlen = sscanf(here,"%o",&num);
                  *here = (char)num;
                  break;

            case 'x':
                  numlen = sscanf(here,"%x",&num);
                  *here = (char) num;
                  break;
            }
            num = here - string + numlen;
            here++;
            memmove(here,here+numlen,len-num );
      }
      return string;
}
```